# What kind of motion is caused by nonzero torques about two parallel axes?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Say on a rigid body there are non-zero torques about two parallel axes. About which axis does it acquire a angular acceleration? I'm looking for a mathematical explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "About which axis does it acquire an angular acceleration?"  Are you asking about the angular acceleration about the bodies centre of mass?

Comment: Can angular acceleration be only and only about the center of mass ? @Farcher

Comment: I am puzzled by what you are asking.  Is it in effect, how can I combine two torques who values are known about two parallel axes into a single torque about one axis?

Answer (score 0):

The expression for torque relative to some point is - $$\vec{N} = \vec{r} \times\vec{F}$$

where $\vec{r}$ points from the reference point to contact point (where the force is applied).
For your scenario - forces about parallel axes will have different $\vec{r}$ values (though may have the same $\vec{F}$ values).

**You must know the tensor of inertia for your object** to know the exact effect of the torque on it. Even for a single contact point (torque applied at single point) **it is possible to cause rotation about arbitrary axis** (i.e arbitrary $\vec{\omega}$) for objects with different mass distribution.

To calculate the axis of rotation you can use the following relations - 
$$\vec{N}=\dot{\vec{J}}$$ and $$\vec{J}=I\vec{\omega}$$